# DataFrame.lookup requires unique index and columns with a recent version of Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, lookup

I am working with python3.7, and I am facing an issue with a recent version of pandas.
Here is my code.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'col_1':[9087.6000, 9135.8000, np.nan, 9102.1000],
        'col_2':[0.1648, 0.1649, '', 5.3379],
        'col_nan':[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'col_name':['col_nan', 'col_1', 'col_2', 'col_nan']
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[101, 102, 102, 104])

col_lookup = 'results'
col_result = 'col_name'
df[col_lookup] = df.lookup(df.index, df[col_result])
```

The code works fine with pandas version 1.0.3, but
when I try with version 1.1.1 the following error occurs:

> "ValueError: DataFrame.lookup requires unique index and columns"

The dataframe indeed includes a duplication of the index "102".

For different reasons, I have to work with version 1.1.1 of pandas. Is there a solution with the "lookup" command to support index duplication with this version of pandas?

Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: kindly post your expected output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put a unique index in place then restore the old index...

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

data = {'col_1':[9087.6000, 9135.8000, np.nan, 9102.1000],
        'col_2':[0.1648, 0.1649, '', 5.3379],
        'col_nan':[np.nan, np.nan, np.nan, np.nan],
        'col_name':['col_nan', 'col_1', 'col_2', 'col_nan']
        }
df = pd.DataFrame(data, index=[101, 102, 102, 104])

col_lookup = 'results'
col_result = 'col_name'
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df[col_lookup] = df.lookup(df.index, df[col_result])
df = df.set_index(df["index"]).drop(columns="index")
```

Comment: Only you miss how it working in oldier pandas version - it create lists for matching duplicated index values, so cannot be used this solution.

Comment: @jezrael ok, however question was how to make it work in pandas 1.1.   If you look at question it doesn't want lists,  row 3 looks up a different column to row 2.  So a list is not desirable.  IMHO this gives correct answer and lookup only makes sense with a unique index - it's a good proper upgrade to pandas.  Backwards compatibility makes no sense

Comment: @Rob Raymond Thank you for this solution which works perfectly and seems to me to be the most optimal (no iteration).

Answer (score 2):

Non-unique index was a bug: [Github link](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/33045)

"look up" method in pandas 1.1.1 does not allows you to pass non-unique index as input argument.
following code has been added at the beginning of "lookup" method in "frame.py" which for me is in(line 3836):

C:\Users\Sajad\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py

```
if not (self.index.is_unique and self.columns.is_unique):
# GH#33041
    raise ValueError("DataFrame.lookup requires unique index and columns")
```

However if this error handler didn't exist, the following procedure in this method would end up in a for loop. substituting the last line with this built-in for loop gives you the same result as previous pandas versions.

```
result = np.empty(len(df.index), dtype="O")
for i, (r, c) in enumerate(zip(df.index, df[col_result])):
    result[i] = df._get_value(r, c)
df[col_lookup] = result
```

Comment: Thanks for the very clear explanation of the origin of this bug. Your solution works well, but working on datasets of sometimes several million rows, I guess iteration with a for loop is not optimal for performance reasons.

Comment: Yes. for loops are always a pain for large data. By the way this is what "look up" does for mixed type data like yours. So it really doesn't matter whether you use an iterator or not. However "look up" is optimal and fast when all data is represented as numpy arrays.